# Multiple definitions of `getNumberOfProcessors` stop linkage with cabal-install

Tags: haskell, debian, cabal, beagleboneblack

I am trying to get cabal 1.20 installed on a beaglebone black rev c (with debian wheezy arm). It fails late in the `cabal install cabal-install` with:

```
[75 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox ( Distribution/Client/Sandbox.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Sandbox.o )
[76 of 76] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/cabal/cabal ...
/usr/lib/ghc/libHSrts.a(OSThreads.o): In function `getNumberOfProcessors':
(.text+0x8): multiple definition of `getNumberOfProcessors'
dist/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/cbits/getnumcores.o:getnumcores.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.20.0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Poking around the haskell runtime library I see `getNumberOfProcesses` is already defined (which would explain the collision):

```
root@doghouse:/# nm /usr/lib/ghc/libHSrts.a  | grep -B 3 Processors
nm: Disassembler.o: no symbols
nm: FrontPanel.o: no symbols
nm: LdvProfile.o: no symbols
         U getAllocations
         U getFullProgArgv
         U getGCStats
         U getNumberOfProcessors
nm: OldARMAtomic.o: no symbols
nm: Papi.o: no symbols
nm: Profiling.o: no symbols
nm: RetainerProfile.o: no symbols
nm: RetainerSet.o: no symbols
nm: RtsDllMain.o: no symbols
nm: Trace.o: no symbols
nm: 0Hash.o: no symbols
nm: 0Unpack.o: no symbols
nm: Dist.o: no symbols
nm: Global.o: no symbols
nm: GranSim.o: no symbols
nm: HLComms.o: no symbols
nm: LLComms.o: no symbols
nm: Pack.o: no symbols
nm: ParInit.o: no symbols
nm: ParTicky.o: no symbols
nm: Parallel.o: no symbols
nm: ParallelDebug.o: no symbols
nm: RBH.o: no symbols
nm: Sanity.o: no symbols
nm: EventLog.o: no symbols
--

OSThreads.o:
00000000 T forkOS_createThread
00000008 T getNumberOfProcessors
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what the cause it, but if all else fails you can always delete the global GHC library folder. Probably a good idea to always build these executables in a sandbox, and then move the executable into `/usr/bin` or any other directory in your path.

Comment: If I delete the global GHC library folder I will lose access to the all-important RTS, won't I? Then no Haskell application will compile or run. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Pretty much, but cabal install will pull in anything you need as you build. From my experience the best way to handle haskell library sources is to use sandboxes to build everything (because `cabal` currently doesn't handle different versions of the same library very well, if at all). What you want is to create like a global sandbox (containing the most common libraries such as `base`) and use that as the base for building binaries, and install any specific libraries you need into your binary's sandbox. You can read more into cabal sandboxes to see what it can do.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

To fix the problem, I patched `cabal-install.cabal` to add `-DHAS_GET_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` to the `cc-options` as [mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/mzp/7179080).